# AngularJS - Remember view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to remember a view. This view is constructed by a controller - which loads contact information on our API server. When the data is loaded into the controller, it is added to the `$scope.contacts` array which is displayed in the view. Now, when we go to another location (by changing the hash) and then go back, the state is not remembered! The whole array is empty, so there is nothing to display in the view. So, it is not possible to go exactly to the position where the user left. How can we accomplish this?

Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$rootScope` instead of `$scope` to persist it across pages.

> Occasionally there are pieces of data that you want to make global to the whole app. For these, you can inject $rootScope and set values on it like any other scope. Since the scopes inherit from the root scope, these values will be available to the expressions attached to directives like ng-show just like values on your local $scope.

[(From the FAQ.)](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq)

Comment: Thanks :)! And how can I call this $routeScope from the view? And how do I remember the exact location where I left when I am going back to that view?

Comment: You'd use it as normal, with `function ($rootScope)` for your controller and then setting $rootScope.contacts. Can you explain your second question more?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `$rootScope` you can make data avaible to all the application and so to all the views.

If you want to persist some data on your client and reuse it in another page you can check the [angular-local-storage module](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)